# How to merge rules on a GitLab CI Job

Tags: yaml, gitlab-ci

Let's suppose I have this hidden "base" job.

```yaml
.base_job:
  rules:
    - if: "$CI_COMMIT_TAG"
      when: never
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "web"'
```

I'd like to add these rules to a new job and be able to extend them too, e.g.:

```yaml
job_1:
  rules:
    - <add .base_job here>
    - if: "$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_IID"


job_2:
  rules:
    - <add .base_job here>
    - if: "$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH"
```

Note that `job_1` and `job_2` have different rules, including the ones from `.base_job`.

If I were to use `extends`, the jobs would have only the custom rule because according to the [docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#merge-details):
`You can use extends to merge hashes but not arrays.`

My solution so far is to copy-paste the rules for both jobs but I'd like to keep it more DRY.

Any tips on how to do it?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

As pointed out in the question, the GitLab CI `extends` construct does not allow one to merge inner arrays (and more generally the expected underlying feature in YAML is [not(yet) available](https://github.com/yaml/yaml/issues/48)), so basically:

```
.base_job:
  rules:
    - if: "$CI_COMMIT_TAG"
      when: never
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "web"'

job_1:
  extends: .base_job
  rules:
    - if: "$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_IID"
```

would lead to:

```
job_1:
  rules:
    - if: "$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_IID"
  # → overwritten
```

#### Alternative solution

However, if you find that [the first answer posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67011828/9164010) is too hacky and too verbose, it appears you could just use the [native YAML anchors construct](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/operators/anchor-and-alias-operators) to do the same.

Namely, you might write a GitLab CI conf-file like this:

```yaml
.base_job:
  rules:
    - &rule_a
      if: "$CI_COMMIT_TAG"
      when: never
    - &rule_b
      if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "web"'
job_a:
  rules:
    - *rule_a
    - if: "$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_IID"
job_b:
  rules:
    - *rule_b
    - if: "$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH"
```

Comment: That looks cool! I'll give it a try. Seems like a better option for now!

Comment: Just confirming it really works, thank you for the help! 

Comment: Hi @ErikMD, I am trying this and `job_b` is triggered even if `*rule_b` is `false` and `if: "$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH"` is `true`. I am wondering if we can replicate `&&` logic between both conditions. I tried changing the order but no luck.

Comment: @RohitBabu indeed, putting several `- if:` amounts to enumerating several *or* conditions. To get an *and* condition, according to [this §](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#rulesif): you should just need to write `- if: … == … && … == …`

Comment: @ErikMD I have tried `*rule_b && $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH` but it is giving lint error. If this isn't possible, it defeats the anchors construct solution. Do you know any better ways?

Comment: @Rohit Babu you didn't try what I said (`&&` must be written within the `- if:`, not after the anchor!)

Answer (score 24):

So I've found a <s>*very hacky*</s> [official](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/yaml_optimization.html#reference-tags) way of doing this. It is not ideal but at least I could get what I wanted working.

**Warning: This is only available starting on GitLab 14.3, which as of Sep/21 is in a pre-release state.**

I prepare a set of just the texts of the rules and inject them in a real rule `if` using [`!reference`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/yaml_optimization.html#reference-tags).

```yaml
.rules_base:
  rules:
    RULE_A: "$CI_COMMIT_TAG"
    RULE_B: "$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_IID"

job_a:
  rules:
    - if: !reference [.rules_base, rules, RULE_A]
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "web"'

job_b:
  rules:
    - if: !reference [.rules_base, rules, RULE_B]
```

This actually works and I can reuse the same rules on different jobs while also including new rules, if necessary.

Comment: Worth noting that GitlabCI started supporting the "!reference" tag in rules [since version 14.3](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/index.html#reference-tags) (check under Version history)

Comment: Thank you @cavpollo, I've updated my answer with that info.

Comment: Well, this is not hacky anymore as it is officially supported from 14.3

Answer (score 5):

You can actually declare a set of rules as an array, and merged them in each job:

```
.base_rules:
  - if: "$CI_COMMIT_TAG"
    when: never
  - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "web"'

.base_job:
  rules: !reference [.base_rules]

job_1:
  rules:
    - if: "$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_ID"
    - !reference [.base_rules]

job_2:
  rules:
    - if: "$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH"
    - !reference [.base_rules]
```

Comment: Is it possible to AND combine several references? Right now it seems multiple if rules are just OR connected

Comment: @Sigmatics No, rules are always combined with OR. But with De Morgan's laws (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws) you can make AND out of OR & NOT. If you can invert the conditions and then create rules for them with `when: never`, you can combine the reverse rules using OR in a way equivalent to having combined the non-reverse rules using AND.