# GitLab CI - Reuse rules with !reference tag results in "invalid YAML" error

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am using GitLab-CI and want to re-use "rules" via `!reference tag` [GitLab Docu](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_control.html#reuse-rules-in-different-jobs). But my pipeline is not running, "invalid yaml".

Here is my simplified `.gitlab-ci.yml`

```yaml
stages:
  - build

.rules_push_only:
    rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push"

build-code:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "$CI_JOB_NAME complete."
  rules:
    - !reference [.rules_push_only, rules]
```

VScode is "complaining" about the last line     `- !reference [.rules_push_only, rules]`

> Unresolved tag: !referenceYAML

This issue, I was able to solve by these answers:

- [VScode fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73666177/cannot-get-reference-to-work-in-gitlab-ci-yaml)
- [Gitlab CI Schema](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/raw/master/app/assets/javascripts/editor/schema/ci.json)

**GitLab Web** says my YAML is invalid `yaml invalid`.

[image: GitLab yaml invalid error]

... but when I am on the Web Editor of the pipeline (with the right branch selected) GitLab wrote "✔️ Pipeline syntax is correct." -> This is confusing; how can I fix something which is not wrong?

[image: pipeline correct in editor]

I am on GitLab v15.10 cloud. How I can un-block myself?

Note: I tried [extends](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#extends) as well and here I can reuse rules. But this does not work for all my flows.

Reference:

- [SO - Q - GitLab CI - Reuse rules with !reference tag](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67028593/10655742)